# how to change account activation from days to hours in Django-registration?

Tags: django, django-registration, django-email

I am using `Django registration app` that sends `email` to the `registered user`s for `confirmation.`
The `default activation window` is

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # One-week activation window;
```

I want to keep the `activation link` open for `two hours`. After which, the link will be `invalid.`
how can I achieve this?

Comment: Be aware that your domain might be greylisted by mail providers, such as gmail, and thus delayed by the server. 2h seems reasonnable but you should not expect a (paying) customer to wait for a mail doing nothing. ==> You should not enforce 2h ; 1 day seems reasonable. (of course, if your emails are sent internally, this will not happen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do:

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2./24 #(2 hours, or 0.0833)
```

The reason this would work is, from the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)

```
expiration_date = datetime.timedelta(days=settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS)
```

and `2./24` in

```
datetime.timedelta(days=settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS)
```

is perfectly valid.

Example:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now() 
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 25, 14, 3, 40, 137723)
>>> datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2./24)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 25, 16, 3, 53, 521675)
>>>
```